# Elasticsearch stats by groups return inconsistent values

Tags: elasticsearch

Environment:

- Elasticsearch version 0.90.2
- 14 nodes
- 3 indices
- 15 mil documents
- ~70 queries/s

I'm querying Elasticsearch search stats by groups using

`curl http://127.0.0.1:9200/_all/_stats/search?groups=_all`

I take the `query_total` values for each index and group out of the results, however I see that I get different results on every 1 in 4 queries I do.

Example:

I run the stats query and get:

```
{
  "indices": {
    "example_index_name": {
      "total": {
        "search": {
          "groups": {
            "group1": {
              "query_total": 50000
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I run the stats query again after 5 seconds and get:

```
{
  "indices": {
    "example_index_name": {
      "total": {
        "search": {
          "groups": {
            "group1": {
              "query_total": 123
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and 5 seconds after that one:

```
{
  "indices": {
    "example_index_name": {
      "total": {
        "search": {
          "groups": {
            "group1": {
              "query_total": 50200
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm guessing the reason for this could be that it's only getting metrics from a few nodes instead of all of them. But if that's the case, can I wait in some way and make sure I have data from all the nodes?

Comment: I also have same problem..!

Comment: What version are you two running? If it's reproducible, then I'd suggest creating an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues).

Comment: @pickypg I'm running 0.90.2 ... I posted this on the elasticsearch mailing list, but I'll create an issue on github too

Comment: @IgorSerko They'll probably ask if it's possible to hook up a more recent release to see what it does. For what it's worth, I tried to see this happen on a v1.1.0 (locally with 0 queries/s) and couldn't reproduce it.

Comment: @pickypg I figured as much, however the current document structure doesn't allow me to migrate to the latest version.